# eclipse does not find bootstrap css in jsp

Tags: css, eclipse, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, eclipse-neon

i am developing dynamic web project with bootstrap templates every thing is working fine even view is rendering perfect.

in home.jsp file in which i have link css(bootstrap files & my customized files) file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
```

but in my code when i press `ctrl+space` it does not show me suggestion for css classes in

```
<div class="..">
```

i am using `eclipse neon` please help me thank

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which Eclipse package you installed you may already have the CSS and HTML editors. If you don't then you can install them using `Help > Install New Software`. Choose the software site for your version of Eclipse in the drop down list and look at the `Web, XML, Jave EE and OSGi` Enterprise Development section. The Eclipse Web Developer Tools section contains the editors you want but the other sections may also be of interest.

**And if this plugin for eclipse will work for you**

Researching this a bit and reading over your comments it seems that you are using Eclipse with the **Aptana extension**. If you absolutely do not need to use the Eclipse environment you could now download the Aptana Studio 3 which is based on Eclipse. It looks just like eclipse but is Aptana. Now instead of entering this and looking for Aptana plugins you are going to go into Aptana and look for eclipse plugins. I've installed this myself and have installed several plugins that handle all sorts of things such as javascript code completion, source code formatting etc.

If you go to this site http://www.aptana.com/ you can download the software there. To get all of the plugins, you can do use this site to guide you through some terrific source code completion utilities as well as others. http://jebaird.com/2012/11/02/useful-plugins-for-aptana-studio-3.html

Comment: Try this @mosean